# ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - React Native App warning mail when uploaded to TesFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store

When ever I uploaded my React Native app to `TestFlight` I am getting a warning mail described below.

> *ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the `aps-environment` entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the 'aps-environment' entitlement. Xcode does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file.*

But I am not using any code for push notification service in my code and I don't need any service from `APNS`. So could any one please help me to rectify the issue in my React Native project. I ejected my expo project and opened it from the `Xcode`. Also in the `Xcode` Push Notification Service is not enabled too in the capabilities section.

My package.json contents are below.

```
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.11",

"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "3.5.2",

"@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1",

"@react-native-picker/picker": "1.16.1",

"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.7",

"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",

"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",

"@shopify/restyle": "^1.4.0",

"@unimodules/core": "^7.1.2",

"@unimodules/react-native-adapter": "^6.3.9",

"axios": "^0.21.4",

"expo": "~42.0.1",

"expo-barcode-scanner": "~10.2.2",

"expo-device": "~3.3.0",

"expo-linear-gradient": "~9.2.0",

"expo-local-authentication": "~11.1.1",

"expo-secure-store": "~10.2.0",

"expo-splash-screen": "~0.11.2",

"expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",

"expo-updates": "~0.8.1",

"jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",

"moment": "^2.29.1",

"react": "16.13.1",

"react-content-loader": "^6.0.3",

"react-dom": "16.13.1",

"react-native": "~0.63.4",

"react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.1.0",

"react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",

"react-native-exception-handler": "^2.10.10",

"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",

"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.4",

"react-native-keyboard-aware-view": "^0.0.14",

"react-native-marquee": "^0.3.2",

"react-native-material-dropdown-upgraded": "^0.11.2",

"react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",

"react-native-phone-call": "^1.0.9",

"react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",

"react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.11",

"react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",

"react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",

"react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",

"react-native-svg": "12.1.1",

"react-native-tiny-toast": "^1.0.7",

"react-native-unimodules": "0.14.10",

"react-native-web": "~0.13.12",

"react-native-woodpicker": "^0.3.10",

"react-navigation": "^4.4.4",

"react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.3.4",

"react-redux": "^7.2.5",

"react-time-picker": "^4.4.3",

"redux-persist": "^6.0.0",

"redux-persist-expo-securestore": "^2.0.0",

"use-immer": "^0.6.0",

"expo-splash-screen": "~0.11.2"
```

Comment: Could you share your `package.json` content? You may use some sort of library or components that use APN.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the package.json contents in it.